# get results from google locations api into array android

Tags: android, google-maps, categories

I have the following URI

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194?q=restaurants");
```

I want to save the result in an Array, and display them as markers on the map. I do not want to open Google Maps for this, I want to do this in my app.I have the following URI Please help me for This

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the result in an array. You can use [`ArrayMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/ArrayMap.html#ArrayMap()), its a generic key value mapping data structure that is designed to be more memory efficient than a traditional HashMap. It keeps its mappings in an array data structure.

In order to launch Google Maps with an intent you must first create an [Intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) object, specifying its action, [URI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse(java.lang.String)) and package.

You could use something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You did see @ThomasLeitner mentioned that ***I do not want to open Google Maps for this***. I think your *In order to launch Google Maps with an intent* is irrelevant.